# i want to send message in amazon sns using nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

previous i was able sent using this code but now iam not able to send it it is showing message id for but the reciver does not received the message how to fix this

```
 async sendMessage(testId: number) {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    
   
    
  

    const sns = new AWS.SNS();

    const message = {
      Message: 'This is the SMS message I want to send.',
      PhoneNumber: '+915876851230',//dummy number
    };

    sns.publish(message, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Message published successfully!');
      }
    });
  }
```

how to fix this error in aws sns it is showing just failed

Comment: If you received any error message while publishing the events, then post that error message in your question so that it will be easier to figure out the problem. And, are you trying to send messages to SNS that is located in cross region? And, do your message publishing service has enough permission to send a message to SNS?

Comment: i just received the status it is failed in sns console while i send message in code it shows success message but when i check sns console it shows message failed

Comment: Do you have a permission to post a message to SNS in aws console? Also, attach screens shots of your failure, so that others can also help with this issue.

Comment: Your async function is not actually async. It neither awaits a promise nor returns a promise.

Comment: FYI the AWS JavaScript v2 SDK can return promises e.g. `sns.publish(message).promise()`.